# how can i get data by using filter?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

hi I'm using MySQL and sequelize

is this right way when I using filter method??

for example, I want to get 1,2,3,4 data

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

const arr2 = arr.filter(v => v != 0)

console.log(arr2);
```

is this right way??

Comment: http://prntscr.com/10h29f5      this is right

Comment: what is relation with `MySQL and sequelize` ?